# CollectionViewSource Filter doesn't work with ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, readonly-collection

I set up an ItemsControl with the items source set to a List.  I then filter this ItemsControl using code like the following:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myList).Filter = filterFunction;
```

This worked as expected. However, I have since changed the items source to a ReadOnlyCollection.  The items still show up in my ItemsControl, but the filter is no longer applied.

Changing the Items source back to a List restores the filter functionality. Is this expected behavior?  How can I use a filter with a ReadOnlyCollection as the items source?

Comment: That's weird, because the the `CollectionViewSource` never actually changes the underlying view.  Shouldn't matter that it's read-only.

Comment: Maybe replace ReadOnlyCollection with ReadOnlyObservableCollection